# Polymer with AngularJS using partial view

Tags: angularjs, polymer, partial-views

This isn't a problem question, but a theory/possibility question. I have made a polymer portfolio site with a list of image links that points to a html page in my file directory for example `/projects/test.html`. The problem that I have is that every time I click on the link it loads the new page because I have it as a separate html.

I read AngularJS can provide partial view. So if I can combine angular, I can keep my website header and just load the content of the links into the partial view.

I was wondering if this is doable, and do I have to fully install angular and change the file structure or can I just import AngularJS file and code from there?

Also AngularJS does provide routing which I will love as it make my url cleaner.I am just asking so I don't have to waste time if this attempt will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all of this is easily achievable with Angular; you will not need to modify Angular. A couple things to get you going. This won't make sense right now but come back once you've dug in a little.

For prettier urls set [`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

You will want your server to serve all 404s for `text/html` requests to return your Angular application (probably `/index.html` on your server). This is so that if someone goes to https://mycoolsite.com/projects/neato (which exists in your Angular app, but NOT on the server) your Angular application will load and the router will display the correct route.